# If I use passport login through facebook is there an additional step before using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, passport.js

I am using passport to login user. If they have logged in using facebook. Does passport return all the information needed to use the facebook graph api? Is there something else I need to do before using the api?

Comment: Why the down vote? Was the question not clear?Can I add more to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token is returned by passport.

providerUserProfile.providerData.accessToken

You can then use that as parameter to graph api.